# How to access and manipulate individual elements in a csv file?

Tags: python, string, csv, split

I'm trying to do some pre-processing of some data in a csv file. The file contains information on various ramen noodles. The 3rd element of each row int the file contains a string of anywhere from 1 or 2 up to 10 words. These words describe the ramen (An example: "Spicy Noodle Chili Garlic Korean", or "Cup Noodles Chicken", etc).

There are over 2,500 reviews and I'm trying to keep track of the 100 most-used words for the descriptions across all the ramens. I then go back through my data, keeping only the words that occur in the 100 most-used. I discard the rest.

For reference, my header looks like this:
Review #,Brand,Variety,Style,Country,Stars,Top Ten

I'm not quite sure how to access the individual words within each description. By description, I'm referring to the 'variety' column.
As a way to test, I have something like:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('ramen-ratings.csv', 'r'))
outputfile = open('variety.txt', 'w')

next(reader)

for line in reader:
    for word in line[2]:
        print(word)
```

But this only prints each individual character, one at a time, on their own line. It's not recognizing the individual words within the string, but instead the individual characters.

Pretty basic question I know, but I'm super new to python so could use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
for word in line[2]:
```

use

```
for word in line[2].split():
```

---

*The explanation:*

`line[2]` is — as you wrote — the *string* of words. By iterating over the string you iterate over its individual characters.

The `.split()` method on the other hand returns the *list of individual words* of that string (which is what you want).

Comment: This is what I was looking for - the .split() function. Wasn't aware of it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `line[2]` is a string, iterating over it means iteration over each character. If you want to iterate over each word, you should split the string to words.

You can use the `split` function for this purpose, which by default splits  by space one string to list of strings (unless you provide another character to split by):

```
for line in reader:
    for word in line[2].split():
        print(word)
```